# How do I use a "get" method to return a private std::unique_ptr member of a class

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have created a class with private, std::unique_ptr members, viz., `m_VBO` and `m_EBO`, as shown.

```
class VAO {

public:
    VAO();
    std::unique_ptr<VBO> GetVBO();
    std::unique_ptr<EBO> GetEBO();

private:
    std::unique_ptr<VBO> m_VBO;
    std::unique_ptr<EBO> m_EBO;
};
```

The class also includes "get" methods to protect and return those members for use when needed.

The definition of those "get" methods is,

```
//*************************************************************************************************
std::unique_ptr<VBO> VAO::GetVBO()
{
    return std::make_unique<VBO>(m_VBO);
    //return std::make_unique<VBO>();
}

//*************************************************************************************************
std::unique_ptr<EBO> VAO::GetEBO()
{
    //return std::make_unique<EBO>(m_EBO);
    return std::make_unique<EBO>();
}
```

which is not working.

I cannot figure out the correct technique for writing the "get" methods.

How is it done?

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Comment: Your design is likely wrong. `VAO` is the **_unique_** owner of this resource. It cannot share the object outside, because it would mean losing unique ownership of the object. You can either (best option) reorganize your logic so that no getters are needed, (slightly worse) transfer the object together with the ownership or (not bad, but worst of these three) make the pointer `std::shared_ptr`, so that it can have many owners.

Comment: Another option would be to return a reference to the pointer.

Comment: If you give someone something unique, you no longer have that thing. You should think twice before doing that.

Comment: Two thoughts, which is better?  First, make member m_VBO a public member of class VAO of type std::unique_ptr<VBO> and exclude the "getter" method.  Second, make m_VBO a private member of class VAO of type VBO, with the same "getter" method, and then instantiate instances of VAO as a std::unique pointer<VAO>.

Answer (score 5):

Unique pointer as name says is unique. So you can't clone it! You can only move it.

So basically depending on your needs there are couple reasonable solutions:

1. Expose reference to object (or raw pointer to object):

```cpp
VBO& VAO::GetVBO() const
{
    return *m_VBO;
}
```

2. Transfer of ownership:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<VBO> VAO::takeVBO()
{
    return std::move(m_VBO);
}
```

3. Provide clone functionality for `VBO`:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<VBO> VAO::clone() const
{
    return std::make_unique<VBO>(*m_VBO);
}
```

4. Change `std::unique_ptr` to `std::shared_ptr`

---

I recommend watching: [Herb Sutter “Leak-Freedom in C++... By Default.”](https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE)

Comment: I will watch the Herb Sutter video.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sharing pointers with others you need to consider who is in charge of life time of the object pointed to.

If there can only ever be a single entity in charge of lifetime, then `std::unique_ptr` is a good choice. You then have the options of either passing lifetime management responsibilities to someone else, by *moving* the unique_ptr. Or you can give out raw pointers if you know that your clients are only observers and will not participate in lifetime management (and you then need to ensure that the entity holding the unique_ptr outlives all observers).

If multiple entities should all be able to individually keep an object alive - shared ownership - then a `std::shared_ptr` is a better choice.

Answer (score -2):

Your get function should look like

```
std::unique_ptr<VBO>& VBO::GetVBO()
{
    return m_VBO;
}
```

Comment: this is crapy solution. Exposing implementation detail

Comment: At least, make the std::uniqe_ptr const, no? Still not great but would at least prevent modifications.

Comment: @Jeffrey: whereas returning `std::unique_ptr<T>&` might make sense (as you may actually modify it), returning `const std::unique_ptr<T>&` is pointless. better to return `/* const */ T*` instead (or reference if not null).